# Error with redirecting input from file to C multiprocessed program

Tags: c, linux, shell, multiprocessing

I input from files  `input1.txt` and `input2.txt` to program with help of shell script, I expect to have in file `a.txt` and `b.txt` content of those files, but in one file is ok, but in another garbage like this `-489663824 -489663824 -489663824 -489663824 -489663824`, who knows what's going on?

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// for multiprocessing
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
// for shared mutex
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_mutexattr_t mutexattr;

void write_to_file(const char *filename, const int n)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "w");
    int value;

    printf("fill file with %d values: ", n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        scanf("%d", &value);
        fprintf(file, "%d ", value);
    }
    fprintf(file, "\n");
    printf("\n");

    fclose(file);
}

void task(const char *filename, pthread_mutex_t *shared_mutex)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(shared_mutex);
    write_to_file(filename, 5);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(shared_mutex);
}

int main()
{
    // mutex routine
    pthread_mutex_t *shared_mutex;
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutexattr);
    pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutexattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
    shared_mutex = (pthread_mutex_t *)mmap(NULL, sizeof(mutex), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
    pthread_mutex_init(shared_mutex, &mutexattr);
    // mutex routine

    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("fork() failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pid == 0) {
        task("b.txt", shared_mutex);
        return 0;
    } else {
        task("a.txt", shared_mutex);
        wait(NULL);
    }

    // mutex routine
    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&mutexattr);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    munmap(shared_mutex, sizeof(mutex));
    // mutex routine

    return 0;
}
```

shell script:

```
echo "9 8 7 6 5 " >> input1.txt
echo "4 3 2 1 0 " >> input2.txt

cat "input1.txt" "input2.txt" | ./test

cmp_files()
{
    if cmp --silent -- "$1" "$2"; 
    then
        echo "write_to_file: ok"
    else
        echo "write_to_file: not ok"
    fi
}

cmp_files "input1.txt" "a.txt"
cmp_files "input2.txt" "b.txt"

rm input1.txt
rm input2.txt
```

Comment: Seems like `scanf` failed. Possibly all the file data went into the buffer in the other process.

Comment: @user253751 I tried flush it but It did not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are pipelining the output of `cat` to your program, one of the processes will cache the input by reading ahead, and it will leave nothing to be read for the `fork` child, or the parent (depending on who takes the mutex first).

Disable stream buffering for `stdin` using `setvbuf()` (manual [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf)), before forking. Add this call on top of your `main()` before reading anything from `stdin` and your application will work:

```
int main()
{
    setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    [...]
```

One process (parent or child, whoever gets there first) is reading ahead and stores the `stdin`'s contents into a buffer. The other process will get `EOF` when running `scanf()` because the `stdin` has no contents left to be read for it, hence the "garbage" values you are seeing in `b.txt`. Those are repeteaded prints of the `value` variable, with the same uninitialized value because `scanf` exited with `EOF` and it never modified it.

Before patching your code with `setvbuf()`, you can check that this is true by verifying what `scanf()` returns:

```
       int ret = scanf("%d", &value);
        if (ret < 0) {
            if (errno == 0) {
                printf("scanf failed: EOF\n");
                break;
            } else {
                printf("scanf failed, errno %d\n", errno);
            }
        }
```

You will see `scanf failed: EOF` being printed by the process that cannot read from stdin.

Comment: This is a reasonable approach, but it might also be good to avoid buffered reads altogether.  Implementing this by reading one char at a time with `read` would be educational.

Comment: can you pls explain or send material on this question: why when we scanf using type command, the process blocked and wait for scanf return?
In this case, it never blocked, and continue to get "garbage" value?

Comment: It is because in the first scenario your program's standard input was piped by the terminal, while in the second scenario your `stdin` is the piped output of the `cat` program. The later one sends `EOF` (closes the pipe) when the printed content ends and sends all at once, allowing your program to read forward when running `scanf`. 
The terminal doesn't send `EOF` unless you explicitly ask to (by pressing `CTRL-D` for example, depending on your terminal). Also, doesn't send input data in advance, it sends only what you type, not allowing the running program to read ahead and cache the input.

Comment: @lidar thanks for your question. I've updated to answer to make a clear statement this happens when pipelining `cat`'s output.